# $div f $ does not change sign in a closed region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ then $\Omega$ does not contain periodic orbits of the system $x'=f(x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Show that if $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is smooth is such that $div f := \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}$ does not change sign in a closed region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with smooth boundary then $\Omega$ does not contain periodic orbits of the system $x'=f(x)$.

The suggestion is to use Green's Theorem.
I tried this:

Suppose that A contains a periodic orbit $\gamma(t)$. By the Divergence Theorem, we have that $$\iint_{\Omega} div f dA= \oint _{\partial \Omega} F \cdot n ds$$
where $F$ is a vector field and $n$ is the normal vector.
Thus, $$\iint_{\Omega} div f dA= \oint _{\partial \Omega} F \cdot n ds= \oint _{\partial \Omega} \dot{\gamma} \cdot n ds= 0 $$ generates a contradiction, as div does not change sign in region $\Omega$.

Is correct? How can I better justify the tickets?